# Oracle - Do filter predicate order change the execution plan?

Tags: oracle, execution, sql-execution-plan

We are troubleshooting a performance problem - The application uses a VIEW and filter predicates applied as below. In the first case, result is retrieved in seconds,but the second one runs for more than an hour.
columns referred in the view actually point to table D. Please note that this view was written for some other purpose and now used for an enhancement(dont know why - management decision).
I can see that the problem is FTS on the partition tables E and F, but not able to understand why/how the order of predicates change the execution plan? this is a cost based approach only and statistics are upto date.
This is not a well formed query - using % eliminates indexes etc - but what puzzles me is why the plan changes when the statement is exchanging filter predicates

> ```
> select COL2 from VIEW where COL3 like
> '%180%'  and COL4 LIKE '%Solu%'
>
> Plan hash value: 1618822878
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Id  | Operation                              | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                           |       |       |  1379K(100)|          |       |       |
>
> PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |*  1 |  FILTER                                |                           |       |       |            |          |       |       |
> |   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER                   |                           |   116K|  8568K|  1077K (19)| 02:47:19 |       |       |
> |*  3 |    HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER               |                           | 97611 |  6481K|   266K  (1)| 00:41:25 |       |       |
> |*  4 |     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN               | IDX1_A | 45156 |   352K|    25   (8)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |   5 |     NESTED LOOPS                       |                           | 97611 |  5719K|   266K  (1)| 00:41:25 |       |       |
> |   6 |      NESTED LOOPS                      |                           | 98629 |  5719K|   266K  (1)| 00:41:25 |       |       |
> |   7 |       VIEW                             | VW_NSO_1                  | 98629 |   674K|    82   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |   8 |        HASH UNIQUE                     |                           | 98629 |  1338K|    82   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |   9 |         UNION-ALL                      |                           |       |       |            |          |       |       |
> |  10 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL             | B                            | 97591 |   667K|    80   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |  11 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL             | C                        |  1038 |  2076 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
>
> PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |* 12 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | PK_D                     |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |* 13 |      TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| D                            |     1 |    53 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
> |  14 |    VIEW                                |                           |     1 |     7 |     8  (25)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |  15 |     UNION ALL PUSHED PREDICATE         |                           |       |       |            |          |       |       |
> |  16 |      SORT UNIQUE                       |                           |     1 |     9 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |* 17 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | IDX1_E                       |     1 |     9 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |  18 |      SORT UNIQUE                       |                           |     1 |     9 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |* 19 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | F                            |     2 |    18 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |* 20 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | G                        |     1 |    36 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |* 21 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | UK_G                     |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

> ```
> select COL2 from VIEW where  COL4 LIKE '%Solu%' AND COL3 like
> '%180%'  ;
>
> Plan hash value: 2380952204
>
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Id  | Pid | Ord | Operation                              | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |   0 |     |  24 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                        |       |       |       |  2598K(100)|          |       |       |
> |*  1 |   0 |  23 |  FILTER                                |                        |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
> |*  2 |   1 |  20 |   HASH JOIN OUTER                      |                        |   116K|  8568K|  7632K|  2295K  (2)| 05:56:38 |       |       |
> |*  3 |   2 |  11 |    HASH JOIN OUTER                     |                        | 97611 |  6481K|  6864K|   266K  (1)| 00:41:27 |       |       |
> |   4 |   3 |   9 |     NESTED LOOPS                       |                        | 97611 |  5719K|       |   266K  (1)| 00:41:25 |       |       |
> |   5 |   4 |   7 |      NESTED LOOPS                      |                        | 98629 |  5719K|       |   266K  (1)| 00:41:25 |       |       |
> |   6 |   5 |   5 |       VIEW                             | VW_NSO_1               | 98629 |   674K|       |    82   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |   7 |   6 |   4 |        HASH UNIQUE                     |                        | 98629 |  1338K|       |    82   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |   8 |   7 |   3 |         UNION-ALL                      |                        |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
> |   9 |   8 |   1 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL             | B                    | 97591 |   667K|       |    80   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |  10 |   8 |   2 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL             | C                    |  1038 |  2076 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |* 11 |   5 |   6 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | PK_D                     |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |* 12 |   4 |   8 |      TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| D                        |     1 |    53 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
> |* 13 |   3 |  10 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | A                    | 45156 |   352K|       |    75   (3)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |  14 |   2 |  19 |    VIEW                                |                        |   127M|   851M|       |  1988K  (3)| 05:08:49 |       |       |
> |  15 |  14 |  18 |     UNION-ALL                          |                        |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
> |  16 |  15 |  14 |      HASH UNIQUE                       |                        |    21M|   184M|   412M|   235K  (4)| 00:36:33 |       |       |
> |  17 |  16 |  13 |       PARTITION RANGE ALL              |                        |    21M|   184M|       |   164K  (4)| 00:25:30 |     1 |    32 |
> |  18 |  17 |  12 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL               | E                        |    21M|   184M|       |   164K  (4)| 00:25:30 |     1 |    32 |
> |  19 |  15 |  17 |      HASH UNIQUE                       |                        |   106M|   910M|  4569M|  1752K  (2)| 04:32:17 |       |       |
> |  20 |  19 |  16 |       PARTITION RANGE ALL              |                        |   238M|  2048M|       |  1286K  (1)| 03:19:54 |     1 |    32 |
> |  21 |  20 |  15 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL               | F                        |   238M|  2048M|       |  1286K  (1)| 03:19:54 |     1 |    32 |
> |* 22 |   1 |  22 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | G                        |     1 |    36 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> |* 23 |  22 |  21 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | UK_G                     |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Comment: From what I know, changing the predicate order should not have any impact on performance. Looking at the given query plans, the `IDX1_A` and `IDX1_E` are being leveraged in the first case, but not the second. Are the predicates exactly identical or different in any way? Can you share the predicates or actual queries?

Comment: @SarathChandra - yes the predicates are exactly same. I have asked to share the view code, will post it if possible

Comment: SQL monitors would be more useful, so that we have the "actuals". Having said that, this is a bit a of a educated guess - the issue is with the push predicate. Can you set the following and retry? alter session set "_push_join_union_view"=false;